# Checking and unchecking checkboxes after postback in Page_PreRender

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dynamic table that's in a update panel. The data of the table gets filled form the code behind. In every row there is a checkbox. After a postback the checkboxes get rechecked if they need to be checked. I have all the items that needs to be chacked in a list. This list gets checked in the PreRenderer. This works fine if the page opens for the first time.

```
void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string CheckedeID in cboCheckedList)
            {
                CheckBox checkedBox = (CheckBox)tbl_main.FindControl(CheckedeID);
                checkedBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
```

After a postback, if a button gets click to change the checked status. The new ID gets added to the cboCheckedList. I can see when I'm debugging the item is in the list and the new item also gets checked. But when I return to the page the checkbox isn't checked.

Am I setting the checkbox in the wrong location? 
Where should I set the checkbox so it will stay checked?

The code of the table in the updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table runat="server" ID="Table1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" GridLines="Both" BackColor="White" class="tablesorter">
                <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow2" runat="server">
                    <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="#CEE3F6" ForeColor="White" Wrap="false" Width="50px"
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NoImage">
                    </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                    ....
                </asp:TableHeaderRow>
            </asp:Table>
        </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: show me your `Page_load` code plz

Comment: I can show you but there are a lot of functions in the onload. Can you tell me what you would like to see so I can give you a shorter code?

Comment: are you using `Ispostback` property of page on `onLoad` or on `pageload`

Comment: I use it in the pageload

Comment: it is a problem of update panel not postbacks; so can you post your update panel code(a sample is fine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the UpdateMode="Conditional" from the update panel did the trick.

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Table runat="server" ID="Table1" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2" GridLines="Both" BackColor="White" class="tablesorter">
                    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="TableHeaderRow2" runat="server">
                        <asp:TableHeaderCell BackColor="#CEE3F6" ForeColor="White" Wrap="false" Width="50px"
                            HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="NoImage">
                        </asp:TableHeaderCell>
                        ....
                    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
                </asp:Table>
            </ContentTemplate>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
```